# iMessage sticker app size export in xcode

Tags: xcode, imessage

I have successfully submitted large, and small sticker packs to the app store. What I  do not know how to do is export a sticker pack that has both large and small stickers that the user can use. I saw a sticker pack that had a tabbed interface in imessage so the user can toggle to both sizes.

Does anyone know how to do this in xcode?
Thank you!

Comment: If there is any custom thing in iMessage App like tabbed or anything else, then that is not a simple sticker pack app that must be an iMessage App & created by coding.